# Irregular pixels in sharpened image when using 3x3 sharpening filter

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to use a 3x3 kernel filter to sharpen a black and white image:
[image: The original image]

Sharpening kernel = [0 -1 0; -1 5 -1; 0 -1 0]

I was trying to use CUDA processing to parallelise the process but the result of the filter produces a lot of abrupt pixels with irregular values:

[image: Erroneous image]

To cross check, I went ahead and used manual serial logic to calculate the result in Python and I got the same result.
But when I used OpenCV's `cv2.filter2D` function it appears to work correctly and gives this output:

[image: correct result]

I've attached a serial implementation of Python code here.

```
import cv2 as cv2
import numpy as np
# load the image into system memory
image = cv2.imread('D:/PythonLab/resources/BlackWhite.jpg', flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

kernel = np.array([[0, -1, 0],
                   [-1, 5,-1],
                   [0, -1, 0]])

image_sharp=np.copy(image)

imrows=image.shape[0]
imcols=image.shape[1]

#pixelindexrow pr, pixelindexcol pc

for pr in range(imrows):
    for pc in range(imcols):
        start_r=pr-1
        start_c=pc-1
        temp=0
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if( start_r+i>=0 and start_r+i<imrows and start_c+j>=0 and start_c+j<imcols):
                    temp=temp+image[start_r+i][start_c+j][0]*kernel[i][j]
                
        image_sharp[pr][pc][0]=temp
        image_sharp[pr][pc][1]=temp
        image_sharp[pr][pc][2]=temp

cv2.imshow('Sharpened', image_sharp)
cv2.imwrite('D:/PythonLab/resources/kernelfilter_MANUAL.jpg', image_sharp)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Are there any other preprocessing steps needed before applying the sharpening filter? I am not sure what to do of pixel values which are not bound in [0,255].

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to clamp your calculated values to 255, i.e. set them to 255 if they exceed that:

```
outputImage[...] = min(255, temp)
```

---

Also, rather than test 4 conditions in an `if` statement inside double-nested loops over 9 values inside double-nested loops over image width and height... you could just run your loops from the second pixel to the penultimate pixel and remove the test:

```
for pr in range(1,imrows-1):
  for pc in range(1,imcols-1):
```

---

Also, I am unsure why you are reading (and saving) your image as colour - why not just load with `cv2.imread(..., cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` ?

Comment: My bad. I was trying to make the Original to work on color images.  I tried with BW. The deviation in pixels after convolution ranged from (-544,1145). which is quite a large value and i dont think Clamping the values will actually sharpen it. The image still looks offputting. Is there a way i can NORMALISE the values to be in [0,255] so that the image looks closer to the sharpened image from CV2 filter